# How many heaters should I put in my barns and coops?

Tags: stardew-valley

I know that I need to put SOME amount of heaters in my barns and coops, but I'm not sure how many is efficient. Can I place too many, as well?

Comment: I've read that one per building is all that is needed, but I haven't made it to Winter yet to confirm personally, or to test what happens if you put multiple heaters and turn the barn into a sauna.

Comment: I'm glad you asked this, because it made me realize that I haven't put a heater in my barn yet. I'm two days into winter. Oops.

Comment: @Fluttershy How dare you not keep your cows warm!!! Shame!

Comment: What happens if I don't warm them?

Comment: I made it through winter with 4 chickens and no heater. So... nothing? It might have stunted their growth and I would have no idea.

Comment: @Zaibis They get unhappier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One heater per building is enough. Putting more than one doesn't really change anything

Answer (score 1):

Heaters matter now, I'm not sure if its from an update or not, but with one heater 2 chicks, 2 ducks and 3 rabbits one heater gave me ZERO goods production and hearts were dropping, money is no object in the game any more so I added a bunch I think 4 per building and things are back to normal.